# Guess the hat colors - Riddle 1

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, meta-knowledge, hat-guessing

I have created several riddles with my brother, and one of my favourite ones is this one. It is based on the classic prisoner hat riddle, but it has a twist.

**TASK**: You have to guess which ones are wearing green hats and which ones are wearing black:

[image]

**DESCRIPTION**: A, B and C can see the hats of their two mates, but not their own hat.
Pay attention to the order, they give tips one by one:

1- A can see the hats B and C are wearing, but he doesn’t know what hat he’s wearing

2- After listening to A, C figures out which hat he must be wearing. So, C says, "I know my hat now". This statement tells A,B and D that C didn't know his hat color before A spoke but he knows it now, after A has spoken

3- Finally, D, who is hidden behind a wall and can’t see anyone, figures out what hat he is wearing, just by hearing what A and C have said.

You don’t know how many green and black hats there are of each color (4 in total, all of them must be wearing one), but they **do** know how many hats there are of each color.
For example, if B were the only black hat, A would know his hat is green.

We already know B is wearing a black hat. You have to guess A's, C's, and D's hat! There is only one possible solution

Comment: This isn't exactly a 'modest' puzzle.

Comment: @GuessHat just wanted to mention that the picture is much appreciated.  I don't see many on here with graphics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious:

> There are not one or four black hats. In either case, A would know his hat color immediately.

Then:

> If there are two black hats, for A to not know his hat color, C must be wearing a green hat. Likewise, if A is wearing the second black hat, C can deduce his own hat is green without A's input. Therefore, A and C's hats are both green. D knows from both A and C that their hats are the same color, in this way. I fail to see how D deduces his own hat color, in this line, though; if he cannot see B, he does not know whether it is black or green, so this does not work out.

> In the case where there are three black hats: neither A nor C can see the single green hat. A's statement tells C that he is not wearing the green hat, leading him to claim that he knows his hat color. Now, let's look at D: he learns from A that neither B nor C is wearing the green hat, and from C that A isn't either. Therefore he must be wearing the green hat.

Thus:

> A, B, and C's hats are black. D's is green.

Comment: rot13(N, O, naq P znxr frafr, ohg jbhyqa'g vg fgvyy or nzovthbhf sbe Q?  Va beqre sbe guvf gb or hanzovthbhf, Q zhfg xabj gung P qvqa'g nyernql xabj gurve ung pbybe orsber gurl fcbxr.  Q pbhyqa'g xabj gung jvgubhg cevbe xabjyrqtr bs P, be gryrcngul.  Q pbhyq nffhzr vg V fhccbfr.)

Comment: I think you're right on that, but I also think the implication would be that ROT13(gurer vf ab fbyhgvba), given the other scenario?

Comment: The reasoning is perfect, I wouldn't have been able to explain it better!!! I just posted a more difficult one, I bet you can't resolve it as quick this time... Good luck! https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102187/find-the-hat-colors-riddle-2

Comment: @GuessHat if this is right, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Braegh Yeah, probably.  I think you found the intended solution, the puzzle probably could use a bit of tightening.

Comment: @mjjf Done, forgot to mark it, thanks! It's one of my first riddles, do you have suggestions to tighten it?

Comment: @GuessHat Yeah, take a look at this comment (it's encrypted to avoid spoiling the puzzle for others, but you can decipher it using rot13.com):  rot13(N, O, naq P znxr frafr, ohg jbhyqa'g vg fgvyy or nzovthbhf sbe Q? Va beqre sbe guvf gb or hanzovthbhf, Q zhfg xabj gung P qvqa'g nyernql xabj gurve ung pbybe orsber gurl fcbxr. Q pbhyqa'g xabj gung jvgubhg cevbe xabjyrqtr bs P, be gryrcngul. Q pbhyq nffhzr vg V fhccbfr.)

Comment: @mjjf ROT13(V trg lbhe cbvag, gurer'f n fznyy fhogvyvgl, naq vg'f gung P fnlf gur jbeq "abj", vzcylvat gung ur qvqa'g xabj orsberunaq. Vg vf gura fcrpvsvrq va gur qrfpevcgvba gung ur qvqa'g xabj orsber, naq Q xabjf guvf gbb.)

Comment: @GuessHat Yeah, I suppose if I was D I would interpret it that way.  It wasn't clear that he knew that for a fact beforehand, but I can see it being the more likely conclusion after hearing the others' discussion.

Comment: @mjjf , I have edited the question to remove the ambiguity.